# Calling SignalR hub from Web API controller without any view

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

I am a beginner in SignalR. I have found a sample that is client and server project, client is wpf and server is ASP.NET Core.

But the server part in the JavaScript file defines the hub and receives or sends the message. I want to have the part written in JavaScript inside the controller, but I do not know how.

In my own server I don't have any view, my server is an ASP.NET Core Web API - I just want to send or receive messages from clients and do something in server, for example I want to receive an specific message from client1 and after process something send a specific message to client2, so I don't need any views and js file.

```html
    //Hub class is :
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user,message);
        }
    }
```

```html
//and js is :

    
var connection = new signalR.HubConnection("/chathub", { logger: signalR.LogLevel.Information });

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var encodedMsg = user + " says " + message;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error;
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});

connection.start().catch(function (err) {
    return console.error;
});
```

Comment: If your webapi project uses signalR functionality (i.e. signalR hub is hosted here), and you wanna use hub-functionality outside hub itself, you should use [hubcontext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0).        Also any related info can be found in the navigation panel on the left side.

Comment: Thank you @Ryan , you solved my problem